# How to locate the name of function in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to locate the name of a function. The steps I'm using are:

1. press `[m` to  locate to the first { of the function.
2. press some `b` to locate the name of the function.

Is there any simple way to locate the name directly?

Comment: What language is the function written in?

Comment: it is Java language

Comment: How about `[mF(b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider installing [vim plugin showfunc.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=397), which would satisfy your need to walk through the functions in the java file.

Also, You can consider using vim editor customized for Java. 
It will help you in listing of packages, classes, functions etc. 
[Spacevim](https://spacevim.org/use-vim-as-a-java-ide/)

Also, you can consider [Exuberant CTags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), which will be helpful, if you want to go to definition from reference and back. It supports Java also. As it is not being maintained any more, as suggested by @Michail, you can go for [Universal CTags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags)

Comment: Universal CTags may be a slightly better option, as it is maintained, unlike Exuberant CTags.